# Instrumenting search term in SharePoint2010

Tags: search, javascript

I know SharePoint2013 can capture this data better but in 2010, i am trying to capture exactly what terms people are searching for.
I have analytics logic that i can call as javascript. 
My search result is displayed in _layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx page but I can't find _layout folder in SharePoint designer nor in Site Settings page. I've also read that it is not a good idea to modify out of box pages like OSSSSearchResults because update can wipe them out without prior warning.
I was thinking about creating my own search result page but i don't see redirect option as mentioned in [redirect search to /search/results.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16829/redirect-search-to-search-results-aspx/17031#17031) and i am guessing it is for 2013?

Anyway to be able to parse search term and call javascript from search result would help me a lot. 
thanks

Comment: Are you using Foundation or Server?

Comment: it is on SharePoint 2013 enterprise. my site collection hasn't been upgraded to 2010.

Comment: Can you clarify your reply?